# Pointer seems to re-set for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

***Edit:*** I also wouldn't mind knowing if this is just way too ambiguous for you to understand and or find what is wrong, I for one know that it isn't directly related to code because the change happens right when I'm about to exit a function ... not during actual "code". So I hope this is enough, regardless I will add more if needed. Thank you in advance!

I am trying to make a simple (one way) linked list, and I have to make it myself, not use STL or any other already made dynamic container. I have made a simple one but I seem to have a problem that I simply can't wrap my head around.

Whenever I make a new node in the list (I always return the first node of a list in case it has been changed, I don't use a "sentinel" or "dummy" Node) the new node is good until I reach a certain point in the program when it resets all by itself to the first node I introduce.

To try and keep my post as clean as possible I will insert less code and more "functionality" or pattern, but if it's not enough I will add more.

Here is how it works:

My Node item

```
struct Node {    // simplified example
    string type;    //can be ignored
    int ap_nr;      // I sort by apartment number
    int sum;        // can also be ignored
    Node *next;
};
```

In main I initialize my first node as a "fake" node (ap_nr = -1, other ap_nr can't be negative).

```
int main ()
{
   int command = 1;   // used for loop
   Node *begin;    // head of my list
   begin = new Node;
   begin = create_node();   // initialize
   while (command != 0)    // This is for work with a "handler", accesses different mechanics of the program, I don't know exactly how to explain in english
   {
       input_command(command, begin);    // reads command, sends result to handler
   }
return 0;
}
```

Here is my input command:

```
void input_command (int &command,Node *begin)
{
    cout<<"Option #"; cin>>command;
    input_validation (command, begin);
}
```

And the only part of my handler that I use atm:

```
void input_validation (int command, Node *begin)
{
     if (command == 1 trough 15)    // pseudo code 
         execute (command)    
}
```

After I add a node to the list, I used debug to track it, and the first one stays as is, but then the second node (I add it before the first one and return the new "begin"), at first it's ok (has a new memory location and `new_begin->next = old_begin` but after I exit the `ìnput_command` structure it resets)

***Here is the input_command structure and a program diagram:***

***Main:*** - initialize 'fake' node / enter menu loop -> goes to input_command.

***UI:*** - input command -> reads command -> validates -> sends to handler.

***List:*** - adds desire node to "list" (there isn't actually a list per se, just linked nodes) -> returns the first node.
First node is ok (has new address, points at old node)

Returns to UI: -> input command (lower bracket) and ***resets*** (what I mean by this is that no matter what node I add, it becomes the first node I added. So let's say I introduce apartments 1 through 10, it only remembers "1").

AM I missing something ? do I have a logic error in my design ?
Do you need more code to asses ?
Just tell me what to add, I realize this is a bit ambiguous.

***Notes:*** Now I can only add nodes before my main node, I won't focus on anything new until I make this work properly, as long as my design is not part of the problem, I won't change that either, but if it's bad I would appreciate notes and suggestions.

This is the only implemented part of the add_node function:

```
Node *add_node (Node *begin,string type, int sum, int ap_nr) // Node begin e primul nod din lista, trebuie mereu plimbat cu toate functiile pe lista
{
// if first node is dummy node

if (begin->ap_nr == -1)
    {
        begin->type = type;
        begin->ap_nr = ap_nr;
        begin->sum = sum;
        begin->next = 0;
        return begin;
    }

 // else create new node and insert it in sorted position

 else
 {

     // if node should be inserted before first node (begin)

     if (ap_nr <begin->ap_nr)
     {
         Node *cursor;
         cursor = new Node;
         cursor->ap_nr = ap_nr;
         cursor->type = type;
         cursor->sum = sum;
         cursor->next = begin;
         return cursor;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the source to the input_command function. I suspect you are not passing a reference to it, so the begin pointer is never really modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RStrad said, the problem you're having is that you want to modify a pointer in a function and have those modifications remain there **outside of that function** as well.

In C/C++, everything is passed by value. If you want a function to change something, you'll need to pass a pointer to that *something*. So in a case where you want to change a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to that pointer, like this:

```
*Node begin;
input_command(command, &begin);
// the pointer itself has an address, which you are sending with &
```

The definition of `input_command()` will then be:

```
void input_command (int &command, Node **begin)
// observe here the pointer to your pointer
```

From inside `input_command()`, your call towards `input_validation` will have to be:

```
input_validation (command, &(*begin));
// the address of the pointer towards which **begin points
```

The definition of `input_validation()` will then be:

```
void input_validation (int command, Node **begin)
```

...and any further calls, say for instance to a function which actually adds a node, will continue to follow this format. In short, if you have a pointer `*P` and you want to modify it in a function you need to send its address `&P`. That function will receive a pointer to a pointer, `**P` and any further calls which will include the address of P will have to be done with `&(*P)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would truly need to see the adding a node to the list code.  From what you describe with adding the node before the current head, the problem is that begin is being modified ONLY in local scope and is not being passed back out of the input_command (i.e. pass by reference or pass by value)

Comment: While I am at collage, and in my country it's regarded as being "really good" it is in fact rubbish, I know very little of pointers, and they haven't explained anything, nor will they. I understand I should learn this by my own, but if I did learn everything they skipped by my own there would be almost no point in coming here. Where I'm getting at is that I don't know how to corectly pass the pointer so that it would be modified both internally and externally (out of my current local function)

Comment: Also it resets to the first allocated node. If the problem is that it's saved locally why wouldn't my original begin also be remembered locally, then destroyed ? but it's not ... it persists.